# Assignment operator in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I understand that, unlike C++, it is not possible to override assignment operator (=) in C# and it is necessary to create a copy method should we want to assign the instance i1 of class C to another instance i2 (of class C).

But here come the dilemma:
I have a generic class T

```
public class Node<T>
{
  public Node<T> Next;
  public Node<T> Previous;
  T Content;

  public Node<T>()
  {
  }
}
```

T can be a generic class like Person or can be a C# standard types like int, double... There is a need to, sometime assign (=) the value of the content T in Node with another content T. It would be nice if there were an assignment operator that could be implemented in the generic class T so that t1=t2 operation would work with generic class and standard types such as int, double... alike.

What are your suggestions since overloading assignment operator is not allowed in C#? I am looking for an elegant solution that would work for both generic classes and standard types so that my code does not have to distinguish different scenarios.

Is it possible to do that? Many thanks!

Comment: In C#, it's rare and very odd to "assign the instance i1 of class C to another instance i2 of class C". In C#, we would have a rebindable reference `r` to class `C`, and we would assign a new instance of `C` to `r`. In C#, if `T` is a class, `T Content` *can only be* a reference. And C# references are rebindable.

Comment: In `C#` there is cloning mechanism for this purpose.

Comment: Why isn't `this.Content = other.Content` work for you? Can you please explain? Also, consider using the built-in `LinkedList<T>` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *always* assign a variable of a given type to another variable of that type.

In other words, writing:

```
public void Reassign(T source)
{
    Content = source;
}
```

will always work. You *do* have to deal with many types being *reference* types so all that is assigned is the reference. If you want to force value copying you would need to add some generic type constraints (`ICloneable` or similar would work, but you would then need wrappers for the common .NET types).

In other words, if you did:

```
public class Node<T> where T : ICloneable
```

You could then write

```
public void Assign(T source)
{
    Content = source.Clone();
}
```

Or if you don't need to recursively value-copy there is always `Object.MemberwiseClone`:

```
public void Assign(T source)
{
    Content = source.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Also, in case you are not aware, .NET already has a doubly linked list in the [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks, Bradley. I think I kinda got the idea your suggestion but I have to admit it is not yet crystal clear for me. (My own limitation) Could you elaborate on how to force copy the content? I am just aware that linkedlist class exist in .Net but does tree<T> also exist? In Tree<T>, when we delete a node<T>, in scenario where the node has both left and right branch, it is necessary to find the proper leaf, copy it to the node we wish to delete and then delete the leaf. That is why I think reference may not work.

Comment: @user1205746 Nope, it would still work with reference copying (perhaps you could elaborate on what is confusing about reference types? Just think of them like pointers). I'll try to elaborate on the value copying anyways though.

Comment: Thanks! By saying it would still work, do you mean the reference would still work even I delete the leaf because there is another "pointer" pointing to the content of the "deleted" leaf, the garbage collector will keep it? In that case, memory consumed should be doubled because the one should be deleted is not necessarily deleted?

Comment: You can learn more about BST's in C# here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @user1205746 In the case of your tree, pretend that the only current reference to the dying leaf is in the parent node, and the only reference to our instance of "T" is in the leaf. If you just assign the parents child reference to whatever new leaf, that leaf's reference count goes to 0 and it is garbage collected, which causes the instance of "T"'s count to go to 0 and also be collected. If however you wanted to save the instance of "T" you could assign that reference to something (now reference count 2) so when the leaf dies its reference count is one

Comment: @user1205746 In no case is memory consumption doubled, because all you are moving around is references; if an object loses all references, it is automatically cleaned up. It is difficult (though not impossible) to get a memory leak in C#, you usually need to have "hidden" references for it to happen (commonly through event registrations).

Comment: @user1205746 In case it wasn't clear, in a leaf deletion scenario you *just need to assign the parent node's variable to the new leaf object*. Everything else will automatically work as you expect.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: I think I understand your explanation now. Thank you for your patience. Just out of curiosity, if reference works, why would one need to force copy the content?

Comment: @user1205746 Its the difference between a *shallow* copy and a *deep* copy. *Many* times a shallow copy is just fine (even most of the time). However, if having two variables point to the same object (and thus changes *through* the variable will propagate) will cause you problems then you need to use a deep copy. TL;DR, you need to make sure you understand the difference between a shallow and deep copy.

Comment: Ah.. I see. I think I can distinguish the difference between shallow and deep copy through your explanation. So, if deep copy is needed, I have to implement the interface iCloneable on T?

Comment: @user1205746 Not necessarily (note that for reasons beyond my comprehension, `ICloneable` is deprecated, MS recommends making your own.). You only need to do that if your object contains reference type variables you also want to deep copy. If you are ok with doing shallow copies of all your members, `Object.MemberwiseClone` is sufficient., as noted in the answer.

Comment: Got it! I think, at this point, shallow copy seems to be fine for me as long as my Content does not have any dependency to other objects outside of itself. Actually, shallow copy (I think) is a better solution, as a change in the Content get populated to all references to the object. Thank you so much for your enlightening explanation!

Comment: @user1205746 Right, most of the time you *do* want shallow copy. The reason I say to make sure that you understand the difference is that using the wrong one can cause some very hard to diagnose bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload the assignment operator, but you can create explicit or implicit type conversion operators. That makes overloading assignments in your case unnecessary:

```
public static implicit operator Node<T>(T value) {
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>();
    node.Content = value;
    return node;
}
```

That makes this assignment perfectly possible:

```
int value = 1;
Node<int> node = value;
```

If you replace `implicit` by `explicit`, you need an explicit type conversion:

```
int value = 1;
Node<int> node = (Node<T>)value;
```

You can also create a conversion in the opposite direction:

```
public static implicit operator T(Node<T> node) {
    return node.Content;
}
```

So you can assign the node to a value:

```
Node<int> node = new Node<int>();
int value = node;
```

You can also convert to different node types:

```
public static implicit operator Node<double>(Node<T> node) {
    Node<double> destinationNode = new Node<double>();
    destinationNode.Content = Convert.ToDouble(node.Content);
    return destinationNode;
}
```

That is pretty much what you need.

Comment: Thanks, Sefe. In case T is a class, let say Person which has 3 properties, ID, FirstName, LastName. How would you assign?

Comment: This answer, while correct, does not seem to address the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Being that any templated class or object you create has to take a data type, you should always be able to assign one to the other.  For example, when you initialize your `Node<T>`, it will still have to take a data type:

```
Node<double> myNode = new Node<double>();
```

And even if you have different instances, with different data types, you can also convert them from one to the other with C#'s `Convert` methods:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx

```
Node<int> mySecondNode = new Node<int>();
Node<string> myThirdNode = new Node<string>();
Node<bool> myFourthNode = new Node<bool>();

myNode.Content = Convert.ToDouble(mySecondNode.Content);
myThirdNode.Content = myNode.ToString();
myFourthNode = Convert.ToBoolean(mySecondNode.Content % 2);
```

And so on....  Overloading operators is fantastic; but C# makes it easy for you.  Also, like Bradley said, the C# libraries have a `LinkedList` class, so you don't need to do all the heavy lifting.  Check it out here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose a slightly different structure that would allow full customization of the content type.

```
public class Node<T> where T : Node<T>
{
    public T Next { get; set; }
    public T Previous { get; set; }
}
```

You cannot use this class directly, but you inherit from it for your content types. For example:

```
public class Student : Node<Student>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return string.Format("ID={0}, Name={1}", ID, Name); }
}
```

Now each `Student` is the contents as well as the list node at the same time. The `Node<T>` class is re-usable.

Now you can add some smarts to the node class. For example:

```
public class Node<T> where T : Node<T>
{        
    public T Next { get; set; }
    public T Previous { get; set; }
    public bool IsRoot { get { return Previous==null; } }
    public bool IsLeaf { get { return Next==null; } }

    public int CountBefore { get { return IsRoot ? 0 : Previous.CountBefore+1; } }
    public int CountAfter { get { return IsLeaf ? 0 : Next.CountAfter+1; } }

    public T InsertAfter(T node)
    {
        var temp = this.Next;
        this.Next=node;
        if(node!=null)
        {
            node.Next=temp;
            node.Previous=this as T;
        }
        if(temp!=null)
        {
            temp.Previous=node;
        }
        return node;
    }
    public T InsertBefore(T node)
    {
        var temp = this.Previous;
        this.Previous=node;
        if(node!=null)
        {
            node.Previous=temp;
            node.Next=this as T;
        }
        if(temp!=null)
        {
            temp.Next=node;
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

which can be used as such:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new Student() { ID=101, Name="Peter" };
        var B = A.InsertAfter(new Student() { ID=102, Name="John" });
        var C = B.InsertBefore(new Student() { ID=103, Name="Mary" });

        //          [A]----[C]----[B]
        //           |      |      |
        // ID       101    103    102
        // Name    Peter  Mary   John
        // IsRoot  true   false  false 
        // IsLeft  false  false  true
        // CountL    0      1      2
        // CountR    2      1      0

    }
}
```